# Regex in Python - Using groups

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I am new to regex, why does this not output 'present'?

```
tale = "It was the best of times, ... far like the present ... of comparison only. "
a = re.compile('p(resent)')
print a.findall(tale)

>>>>['resent']
```

Comment: coz the group your regex is searching is `'resent'` here. can you provide a better example of expected input/output?

Comment: I expected it to output the string 'present' in a list of one element ('present' only occurs once in the string, tale). I believed that I was searching for instances of 'resent' preceded by a 'p'.

Comment: expected output for this : `tale="resent present ppresent presentt"`?

Comment: @Chet, the groups are what's inside of the parentesis

Comment: The output I expected from the above line was: ['resent','present']

Comment: @Chet I too do not understand this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups

If you want it to just use the group for grouping, but not for capturing, use a non-capture group:

```
a = re.compile('p(?:resent)')
```

For this regular expression, there's no point in it, but for more complex regular expressions it can be appropriate, e.g.:

```
a = re.compile('p(?:resent|eople)')
```

will match either 'present' or 'people'.

Comment: Ok, cool. This explains how to do what I was trying to do. Can you explain to me what my previous code was looking for (why was the p disregarded)? Thank you very much.

Comment: It was being used in matching, but not being captured in the return info. An example would be if you wanted to find a percentage, but only cared about the number part -- you would use the regex `(\d+)%`.

Comment: So once parentheses are included, only things inside the parenthesis are captured?

Comment: @Chet, when using `re.findall`, yes. If no parentheses are found then the entire string will be the result element. When using `search` or `match`, you can specify the entire string by using `result.group(0)` or access the groups with `result.group(1)` etc.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not too familiar with Python regex, but could OP have used two groups in his/her regex? Say if `a = re.compile('(p(resent))')`?

Comment: @BlueMagister Not too familiar with Python myself, but that might work. I think it would return `['present', 'resent']`.

Answer (score 3):

try something like this if you're trying to match the exact word `present` here:

```
In [297]: tale="resent present ppresent presentt"

In [298]: re.findall(r"\bpresent\b",tale)
Out[298]: ['present']
```